# For loop with array not printing the proper result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

New on js , code is below. Here i am unable print the proper result. I think there is something wrong with `+ "names[i]"` this portion of code.

```
var names = ["aha","mk", "jk","hk","fhf"];
for (i=1;i<=names.length;i++){
    console.log("I know someone called "+ "names[i]");
    }
```

Comment: Don't use quotes for `names[i]`. Do this `console.log("I know someone called "+ names[i]);`

Comment: Quotes are to be used only for strings , arrays don't need them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit the quotes around names[i].
It should be:

```
var names = ["aha","mk", "jk","hk","fhf"];
for (i=1;i<=names.length;i++){
    console.log("I know someone called "+ names[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks #aranya for help its fixed

Answer (score 1):

don't use `names[i]` in quotes it's an `expression` to provide your values

you can make use of `es6` template strings

```
var names = ["aha","mk", "jk","hk","fhf"];
   for (i=0;i<=names.length-1;i++){
       console.log(`I know someone called ${names[i]}`);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ["aha","mk", "jk","hk","fhf"];
for (i=1;i<=names.length;i++){
    console.log("I know someone called "+ names[i]);
    }
```

names[i] is a string already.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that names[i] should not keep in double quotes and change i value to 0

```
 var names = ["aha","mk", "jk","hk","fhf"];
 for (i=0;i<=names.length;i++)
 {
      console.log("I know someone called "+ names[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

- **FIRST** of all: Just as everyone has been saying, you do not place `names[i]` within double quotes, since it is a reference to a defined variable.
- **SECOND**: The **
  ** statement in your `for` loop is `i<=names.length`, but it should be `i<names.length`. Your way would've gone all the way to 6, which is too high.
- **THIRD**: In addition to the second mistake, you must also change `names[i]` to `names[i--]`, because `i<names.length` would still reach 5, and 1 is too high of a number to start with.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is working properly 
You need to remove = sign and set i = 0

```
var names = ["aha","mk", "jk","hk","fhf"];
        for (i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        console.log("I know someone called "+ names[i]);
    }
```